# Why nested routing is not working in react{not rendering)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, router

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzR9Q.png)

I am trying to implement react router which is actually a nested router when i am clicking the links in contact page it is not showing the results. Please help me.
Github link : https://github.com/abhinaisai2002/router

Comment: Please add your code in here instead of using images

Comment: once check the github link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you are using `exact` for `"/contact"` route, that's why nested route is not working, just remove it and try again.

Comment: hey can u plz say why it is showing like that when i used exact for /contact

Comment: @AbhinaiSai If you use exact then it will not render contact component for "/contact/posts" because it will render only when route will be "/contact"

Comment: got u bro , you are life saver